# How to copy marked text in notepad++ automatical

Tags: notepad++, settings

Is there a way to say notepad++, copy marked text to clipboard? 
The text was marked with the mouse.
Like putty does.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. You have to Ctrl + C